# List all Ubercart product fields found in uc_product_field_extra_fields()

Tags: ubercart, entities

I am trying to use the Fields API to list all of the Ubercart product fields (cost, model, sell_price, weight, etc). I have tried

```
entity_get_info('node')
field_info_bundles()
field_info_instances('node', 'product')
field_info_extra_fields('node', 'product', 'form')
```

`field_info_instances()` gives me the image field and the catalog taxonomy, but none of them return the fields added by [uc_product_field_extra_fields()](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!uc_product!uc_product.module/function/uc_product_field_extra_fields/7). I thought for sure `field_info_extra_fields()` would return it, but all I get back is `title` and `path`. What is the correct API call to list these fields? I don't need them in display form or anything like that.

I'm using Drupal 7.12 and Ubercart 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in `uc_product_field_extra_fields()`, the extra fields are defined for 'display' and not for 'form'. The correct call is `field_info_extra_fields('node', 'product', 'display');`